# Como agregar una imagen desde una base de datos a un side menu en ionic 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Tengo un problema, ¿donde debería cargar la imagen que viene de la base de datos y visualizarlo en el Side Menu?. Regularmente yo lo hago desde el archivo app.components.ts  pero cuando el usuario se loguea por primera vez lo que hace la aplicación es registrar su datos en LocalStorage para que pueda iniciar sesion sin volver introducir sus datos otra vez. Es aquí donde surge el problema... no carga el logotipo en el Side Menu, aparece una imagen rota. pero ¿por qué sucede esto?
Ejemplo:

Como veran este es mi codigo que esta en el archivo app.components.ts este lo llamo en el método ngOnInit. Lo que hace primero es dentro de una promesa espera que obtenga los datos que estan en el **localstorage** El metodo que uso para  obtener los datos es el **this.serviceSql.getDatosUsuario()**

```
  async logoEmpresa(){
        const promesa = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          this.serviceSql.getDatosUsuario().then( data =>{
                if(data != null){
                    const datos = {
                      idEmpleado: data['idEmplead'],
                      idCliente: data['password']
                    }
                      this.service.getURLlogo(datos)
                      .subscribe(result => {
                            resolve(result);
                      },error => {
                        reject("Ocurrio un error, verifique su conexión de internet");
                      });
                }else{

                }
        }).catch( error => {
          this.logoEmpresa();
        });
      });
      promesa.then((response) => {
        this.urlLogo = 'https://mipagina.com.mx/'+response['urlLogo'];
      }).catch((error) =>{
      });
  }
```

Codigo del metodo donde llamo los datos del usuario en el localStorage

```
  getDatosUsuario(){
return this.isReady()
.then(()=>{
  return this.database.executeSql(`SELECT * FROM usuario`, [])
  .then((data)=>{
    if(data.rows.length){
      return data.rows.item(0);
    }
    return null;
  })
})
```

Al parecer aquí todo va bien porque intenta obtener los datos guardados y enviarlos a una api donde este devuelve un base64 de la imagen y lo carga a una URL que este mismo es agregado al archivo app.components.html

```
<ion-toolbar color="tertiary" class="ion-text-center" style="padding: 4%;">
                <!-- <img src="../assets/ipaed.jpeg" width="50%" /> -->
                <img [src]="urlLogo" width="40%" />
</ion-toolbar>
```

El problema surge cuando el usuario se registra por primera vez y el app.components.ts parece que se ejecuta primero antes que cualquier archivo page  entonces al no haber datos en el localstorage significa que la url no tiene información y por la misma razón no aparece una imagen sino esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cierro la app  o finalizó y lo vuelvo abrir, inicia sesión automático porque ya tiene información en el localstorage entonces aquí mi método si funciona porque al haber datos guardados y el método **this.serviceSql.getDatosUsuario()** ahora si obtiene los datos.  Entonces los datos son enviados por la api y este devuelve la imagen en base64... ahora si se visualiza en el Side Menu.

Entonces el problema es este ¿En donde debería poner el metodo logoEmpresa si no es en el app.components.ts? para que la imagen se visualice en el Side Menu ya que el side mene se carga junto con el app.components.ts

Comment: Hola Luis, tu pregunta está un poco confusa, es decir, no está muy claro el flujo que sigues en tu app. Te recomiendo detallar un poco más y dividir los pasos que haces para entender mejor. En adición, agregar también más de tu código en app.component y el código que ejecutas al iniciar sesión. Intenta agregar a tu pregunta un demo reproducible. Solo un comentario, recuerda que `localStorage` es bloqueante, es decir, síncrono, pueda ser que léas la foto en un momento donde realmente aún no está. Sería de ayuda el uso de `Subject` para que notifiques a tu sidebar cuándo leer del localStorage.

Comment: – RRGT19 Claro, intente hacerlo. Y tienes razón el metodo intenta leer informacion donde no hay y por eso mismo es que la url no esta completa lo que significa que no hay imagen que visualizar  y esto genera una imagen rota, pero al abrir otra vez la app ya tiene informacion en el localstorage  y ahora si hay imagen que visualizar

Comment: Lo siento pero, no logro entender el flujo viendo tu código, la explicación es confusa y tampoco queda claro dónde tienes el método `getDatosUsuario()`. Te recomiendo que, en tu servicio tengas un `BehaviorSubject` el cuál envíes la data del usuario una vez haga log in. Luego, en el componente donde quieres mostrar la foto, te suscribas al `BehaviorSubject` anterior y cargues la url de la foto en una variable local, de esta forma tendrás garantía que la url se le asignará un valor tan pronto hayas hecho `next()` desde cualquier sitio.

Comment: Lo siento, pero no es mucho lo que tengo, solo en el login guardo los datos en el local storage, y en el app.components recupero los datos del localsotorage. Investigare lo que me acabas de mencionar porque nunca lo he visto gracias bro

Comment: Según lo último que comentas creo que he visto una posible causa. El app.component es el primero en inicializar por lo que estás cargando de localstorage de manera anticipada. Imagino que luego de hacer log in en tu login.component redireccionas a otro componente? Si es asi, en ese otro componente es que debes cargar de localstorage. El app.component por defecto y por configuración en el app.module es el primero en ser arrancado y por tanto no tendrá nada en localstorage la primera vez, pero si la segunda vez y por eso es que luego puedes ver la imagen en pantalla.

Comment: Asi es, esa es la causa en el app.components.ts al leer lo del localstorage y ve que no tiene informacion aun se ejecuta, porque el login aun no se ha cargando y guardado información asi que estoy haciendo mas las cosas porque primero deberia cargar el login

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111063/discussion-between-rrgt19-and-luis-hernandez).

Comment: Que lio jajaj no se como usar el chat privado si es que lo es. Pero sigo aqui